# Swift UIButton .setTitle not working

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I am programmatically creating a set of buttons on my VC. I am adding a target for the buttons when creating them and in the function that gets called I am changing the background image and trying to remove the title. However, the title is not changing but the background image is changing which doesn't make sense to me.

```
func createButton(xPos: Int, yPos: Int, width: Int, height: Int, buttonIndex: Int) -> UIButton {
    var button = UIButton()
    button.frame = CGRect(x: xPos , y: yPos, width: width, height: height)
    button.userInteractionEnabled = true
    button.layer.masksToBounds = true
    var buttonImage = UIImage(named: "Display_Icon")
    button.tag = buttonIndex
    button.setBackgroundImage(buttonImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button.setTitle("\(buttonIndex)", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    var titleColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 104/255.0, blue: 178/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    button.setTitleColor(titleColor, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: "screenSelected:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    return button
}

func screenSelected(button: UIButton!) {

    if hasError { hasError = false; return }
    let screenIndex = button.titleLabel!.text!

    if contains(buttonsSelectedArray, screenIndex) {
        return
    }

    buttonsSelectedArray.append(screenIndex)
    var buttonImage = UIImage(named: "DisplaySelected_Icon")
    button.setBackgroundImage(buttonImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button.setTitle("", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    var titleColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    button.setTitleColor(titleColor, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Comment: Use the debugger to see whether your code is executing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Problem that u add target button in old method(Obj-c)

```
func createButton(xPos: Int, yPos: Int, width: Int, height: Int, buttonIndex: Int) -> UIButton {
    ....
    ....
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(UIViewController. screenSelected(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    return button
}  





@IBAction func screenSelected(button: UIButton!) {

    if hasError { hasError = false; return }
    let screenIndex = button.titleLabel!.text!

    if contains(buttonsSelectedArray, screenIndex) {
        return
    }

    buttonsSelectedArray.append(screenIndex)
    var buttonImage = UIImage(named: "DisplaySelected_Icon")
    button.setBackgroundImage(buttonImage, forState: .normal)
    button.setTitle("", forState: .normal)
    var titleColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    button.setTitleColor(titleColor, forState: .normal)
}
```

Comment: @sasquatch My answer has been updated for swift 3 now, Please check it. If u have any doubt don't hesitate to comment, Thank u

Comment: I just don't see how it answers the question. OP is already using `setTitle` but not getting desired result

Comment: @sasquatch, Oh Sry for inconvenience  Please try above that i updated for your question :)

Answer (score -1):

You need to set your button title like this

> button.setTitle("Button Title Here", for: UIControlState.normal)

IOS no longer supports using

> button.titleLabel?.text= "Button Title"

because you are required to set your title with its UIControlState which is either selected, normal, highlighted or whatever it is.

Please see the documentation from this https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uibutton/1624018-settitle?language=objc